# [ViewController row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to pass a selected object in my collection view to another view controller, through a segue. When I click on one cell in the collection view the app crashes and gives me this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136d1fbf0

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self refresh];
}

- (void)refresh {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"People"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo);
        } else {
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Do nothing");
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profilePush" sender:self];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FriendsTableViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FriendsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.friendsDelegate = self;

        PFObject *friendObj = [_friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         [(PFFile*)friendObj[@"profilePic"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {return;}
             cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
         }];

         cell.nameL.text = friendObj[@"username"];

         return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
         return 3;
    } else {
        return _friends.count;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profilePush"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
        ProfilePopupViewController *person = segue.destinationViewController;
        person.user = [_friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //.user is a PFObject in the next view controller
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `prepareForSegue:sender:` the `sender` is not `indexPath`. Use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` instead to identify selected cells

Answer (score 0):

Bug is come from here.

The Sender in prepareForSegue, is viewController.

And you are casting viewController as NSIndexPath

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
 ProfilePopupViewController *person = segue.destinationViewController;
 person.user = [_friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```